# Xamarin Android Player Freezing

Tags: android, xamarin

I've setup the latest Xamarin Android Player (XAP) on my AMD64 server running Windows Server 2012

Hyper V has been uninstalled.

Before doing so I uninstalled Virtual Box and let XAP install its version.

When I start XAP with device Nexus 7 Lollipop it boots to the Android logo and goes no further.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to post errors and logs.

VirtualBox should be installed I believe for the Android Xamarin emulator to work.

However, you could try reinstalling the Android player. Make sure virtualization is enabled in bios.

If worse comes to worse, you can install the Android AVD manager and use the normal Android emulator which also works on Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

The Xamarin Android Player is still in preview, any issues with can be addressed with bug report at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/newbug

Please include the logs when you file a bug, you can generate logs by Right-click bottom bar > Generate Bug Report

In the meantime, I would recommend you to use [Visual Studio Android emulators](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Prashant suggests, you can also try a different simulator image. Some of the XAP device images seem to be unable to boot properly on some machines. I've not seen any issues under OSX version of XAP, but the Windows version seems to be affected on some systems.